# Object.freeze() freezing prototype instances?

Tags: javascript

Does `Object.freeze()` freeze the prototype of an object if you freeze one of the objects instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course when you freeze an object also its prototypes freeze because a frozen object can no longer be changed. We cannot add, edit, or remove properties from it.
**for example:**

```
const counter = Object.create(counterPrototype);
counter.count = 0;

counter.increment = function(){
  console.log('increment')
}
//Cannot assign to read only property 'increment' of object

console.log(counter.increment());
//1
```

As you can see now that the prototype is frozen we are not able to change the `increment()`method in the `counter` object.
The prototype is usually used to keep the methods that are shared between different objects.
Freezing the prototype does not allow us to change those properties in the objects inheriting from that prototype. The other properties can be changed.

Comment: Are you sure this is a correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Freeze {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
const cold = new Freeze("Justin is cool")
Object.freeze(cold)
Freeze.prototype.size = 666
cold.size // 666
```

freezing one of the objects instances does not freeze the prototype of the class/constructor it only freezes the instance.